# How do I use the if statement with WMIC

Tags: batch-file, command-line

this is my first post. I am using a batch command to check if an instance of my program is already running based on its command line argument. I am able to see if it is running by using the following code:

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%Account A%' AND Caption Like '%Leads Manager.exe%'"
```

If the process exists, I will get a full break down of the process information, but if the process isn't running i get `No Instance(s) Available.`

I want to be able to run an If statement, so if the result shows `No Instance(s) Available.` I want to run a command without displaying the process information and if it does exists, I want to echo `Account A is already running`

Hopefully someone with more experience can point me in the right direction

Comment: I would assume you could use Conditional execution using `&&` and `||` or use `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable with the `IF` command.

Comment: Put `2>Nul` at the end of the command. As a side note, in this case, you can change `wmic Path win32_process` to `WMIC Process`.

Comment: You might find https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html to be of interest; alternatively, look into the possibility of using PowerShell and the [`Get-WMIObject` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Please be careful when using the `Like` query wildcard, **`%`**. Only use it where you need to, for instance it is unlikely that the `Caption` ends with anything other than `.exe`, and as it is almost always the same string as that provided under `Name`, doesn't usually begin with an unknown either. I cannot help you with the `CommandLine`, because I don't know your program or how it is run, but this should be more of an improvement for now, `WMIC Process Where "Name='Leads Manager.exe' And CommandLine Like '%Account A%'" [Assoc|Call|Create|Delete|Get|List]…`

Comment: @compo Thanks for the help, I have managed to tidy up the initial query but I still can't work out how to determine how to use the If statement

I have `wmic Process Where "Name='Leads Manager.exe' And CommandLine Like '%Account A%'" 2> Nul`

Comment: @MadDire, can you expand on what you're doing? i.e. what are you doing when the process is running, and when it isn't running? You'll also note that my previous comment shows `6` valid commands one of which, _(with its properties/verbs/methods)_, should generally follow your closing doublequote, before the `2>Nul` is appended.

Comment: @Compo Sure, I am using several .bat files (Account A.bat, Account B.bat etc) to automate tasks, one of which will launch leads manager.exe with the Command Line specifying the path of the .ini to use. This already works

Example: To launch Account A I will run the following command `C:\Leads Manager.exe -- C:\Account A.ini` Once this is running, if, lets say I then want to launch 'Account B.bat' it will check if Account B exists and if it is not found in list of processes with CommandLine Like '%Account B%' it will allow me to then run the command  `C:\Leads Manager.exe -- C:\Account B.ini`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, which may help you out:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (A B C D) Do WMIC Process Where^
 "Name='Leads Manager.exe' And Not CommandLine Like '%%Account %A%%%'"^
 Get Name 2>Nul|Find "Name">Nul && (
        Start "" "C:\Leads Manager.exe" -- "C:\Account %%A.ini")
```

This example uses the outer `For` loop to choose the Account letters, it is therfore checking to see if `Leads Manager.exe` is running with a commandline containing the string `Account A`, `Account B`, `Account C` or `Account D`, and if not it should run Leads Manager specifying the path to the appropriate account. *(Please note that your `.exe` and `.ini` file paths both contain spaces, so I have doublequoted them, but left the rest of the command as you wrote it in your comment. You may want to consider checking that what you provided was correct and adjust it as necessary before testing, or replace that line entirely with a simple `Echo Is Not Running) || Echo Is Running)` statement, or perhaps run another batch file instead).*